# Python парсинг в базу данных

Tags: python, postgresql, rest, crud

У меня есть код на фрейме Sanic:

```
 @app.route('/client', methods=["POST", "OPTIONS"])
async def create_client(request):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', password='baldauren15', database='pyDB', host='127.0.0.1', port=5432)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    if request.method == "POST":
        client = request.json.get('name')
        clients.append(client)
        insert_cl = sql.SQL('INSERT into clients(client_name) values ({})').format(
            sql.SQL(',').join(map(sql.Literal, clients)))
        cursor.execute(insert_cl)
        conn.commit()
        return response.json({"Name": client, "status": "saved"})
    else:
        return response.json({})
```

Здесь с помощью POST осуществляется INSERT в базу и оно более чем работает, но это когда я делаю POST запрос первый раз, а когда хочу сделать еще раз за один запуск у меня две данные вписываются в одну sql и производит такую ошибку:

> ```
> psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: ОШИБКА:  INSERT contains more expressions than target columns
> LINE 1: ...SERT into clients(client_name) values ('Allan','Kane'...
> ```

Я думал чтоб сюда перед INSERT  устроить цикл чтоб он работал циклично но что то пошло не так и ошибок стало еще больше. Подскажите как менять логику кода или все же можно через цикл, если да то как)

Comment: Если ответ по ссылке вас не устроит, возвращайтесь с дополнительными комментариями, будем думать. Но скорее всего вам подойдёт использование `executemany`.

Comment: Хорошо я исправил прошлую ошибку используя list.clear() тем самым дав возможность создать некий цикл. Но у меня теперь другой вопрос как можно сделать так что на одном запросе можно сразу несколько заказов. У меня есть таблица orders и там заказы хранятся и сейчас через POST у меня каждую 1 еду пишет как 1 заказ то есть  если человек сделает сразу 4 кофе или разные напитки могу ли я на одном запросе POST сразу закинуть в базу 4 записей? вот это наверное потребует цикл

Comment: Ещё раз. Одна запись - `execute`, много записей - `executemany`.

Comment: [ERROR] Exception occurred while handling uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/client'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "handle_request", line 97, in handle_request
  File "C:\Users\nurty\PycharmProjects\crud\Post_order.py", line 119, in create_client
    cursor.executemany(insert_cl)
TypeError: function missing required argument 'vars_list' (pos 2)

Comment: Дело в том что у меня POST запрос сейчас работает только для одной запись в базу а мне надо так что б запросе можно комбинировать и сразу скинуть на базу о заказе

Comment: Почитайте для начала ссылку, на которую я сделал дубликатом ваш вопрос. Там написано, как правильно задавать параметры запроса. И в случае одного параметра и в случае списка. Пока вы с этим не разберётесь, дальше разговаривать без толку. Вы не должны "вручную" строки запроса собирать, как вы это в вашем коде делаете.